# Authenticating requests Auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0, cloudflare

Could someone explain how I authenticate my requests with auth0. I am using cloudflare workers for requests, and react for my frontend framework, although I'm sure this is irrelevant. My understanding is to verify the person sending the request is legit, I would send the jwt token from auth0 in the request header, then I would ask on my server for that persons token from auth0, and then I can check these are the same thus verifying the user is legit etc. Is this right or not? and could someone explain in greater detail like how do I get the users token from auth0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tutorial in the Cloudflare documentation? [Authorize users with Auth0](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/tutorials/authorize-users-with-auth0).
It should be a great starting point to understand the process.